# Asp.Net Core check password for admin

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to have a supervisor be able to override for a user

eg. person fails an inspection and needs a supervisor to verify that it is okay to continue.

I currently have a form that returns a username and password from a view. I want to be able to verify that they are a supervisor without logging them in.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> verify(verifyViewModel model)
    {     //this creates the user and their subdomain
         string str_UserName = model.UserName + "@" + model.Subdomain;
            var verify = await _userManager.VerifyPasswordAsync(str_UserName, model.Password);
         if (verify == true){ continue with program }
```

Model:

```
    public class verifyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Subdomain { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }


}
```

with

```
_userManager.VerifyPasswordAsync(str_UserName, model.Password);
```

I think I am missing something but I have no idea where to continue from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task<bool> VerifyAdmin(string username, string password)
    {   //GET THE USER WE WANT TO VERIFY.                                          //model.UserName
        var userToVerify = await _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == username);
        //IF THE USER IS NOT AN ADMIN, RETURN FALSE.
        if (!userToVerify.IsAdmin)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //INITIALIZE RESULT.
        bool result = false;
        //CHECK THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD.   
        result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userToVerify, password);
        //RETURN THE RESULT.
        return result;
    }
```

This is the solution that we eventually came up with. Feel free to suggest changes or upgrades!